# Can not figure outsyntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying my database and `recordID` is an int.  I have this line of code when I echo out the value of `$content['recordID']` it prints out a numeric value, but when I put it in here I get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING.

But if I replace `$content['recordID']` with a numeric value it works properly

```
$sqlCommentAmount = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `recordID` = $content['recordID']";
```

Comment: You should really be using parameter binding. Makes this sort of problem a thing of the past

Comment: and not to mention that sql injection attacks

Answer (score 2):

Leave out the `''` within the `[]`

```
... $content[recordID]";
```

see the documentation example #8: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

**Example #8 Simple syntax example**

```
<?php
$juices = array("apple", "orange", "koolaid1" => "purple");

echo "He drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;
echo "He drank some $juices[1] juice.".PHP_EOL;
echo "He drank some juice made of $juice[0]s.".PHP_EOL; // Won't work
echo "He drank some $juices[koolaid1] juice.".PHP_EOL;
(...)
```

The above example will output:

```
He drank some apple juice.
He drank some orange juice.
He drank some juice made of s.
He drank some purple juice.
(...)    

For anything more complex, you should use the complex syntax.
```

Comment: @user2692006 ... because the documentation says so ;-) ... see my edit!

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 The reference I quote says you CAN do that. What's the point then? I don't mind the -1.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 You are actually incorrect. See the example here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-79. Also, note the **Note** here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar.why

Comment: Did you read the comment preceding the example: `This is wrong for the same reason as $foo[bar] is wrong  outside a string. In other words, it will still work, but only because PHP first looks for a constant named foo; an error of level E_NOTICE (undefined constant) will be thrown.`

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 You seem to have missed the fact that this is **not** *"outside a string"*.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing associative array values and object properties within an interpolated string require squiggly brackets (braces) around the name:

```
$sqlCommentAmount = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `recordID` = {$content['recordID']}";
```

Source [(PHP: Strings)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple):

> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }.

On a side note, you should really use [PDO](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and write prepared statements like this:

```
$sqlCommentAmount = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `recordID` = :recordID;";
```

Then you would bind the parameters by preparing the statement:

```
// ... initialize $db
$stmtCommentAmount = $db->prepare($sqlCommentAmount);
$stmtCommentAmount->bindValue(':recordID', $content['recordID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmtCommentAmount->execute();
```

With your original code, it's relatively safe if you completely sure that `$content` is an integer, but if it's being passed in through a `$_GET` (for example), then your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I'd use `bindParam()` here as you have the value in a variable. Just my opinion though, good answer

Answer (score 0):

`$content['recordID']` is your problem.

You need to take out the quotes around `recordID` I think.

Answer (score 0):

A variable in double quotes can lead to problems. Instead i would try either

```
$sqlCommentAmount = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE recordID = " .$content['recordID'];
```

or

```
$sqlCommentAmount = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE recordID = ${content['recordID']}";
```

Comment: Double-quoted strings were meant to be used with interpolated variables. It's the array key that's causing a problem.